# "eminent" vs. "preeminent"

Tags: meaning, differences

Judging from their entries in Merriam-Webster, the meanings of *eminent* and *preeminent* are similar:

> **[eminent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eminent):**
>
> 1. exhibiting eminence especially in standing above others in some quality or position
> 2. standing out so as to be readily perceived or noted
> 3. jutting out
>
> **[preeminent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preeminent):**
>
> 1. having paramount rank, dignity, or importance

So when would I use which? Is *preeminent* simply stronger, or are there cases where only one of them is appropriate?

Comment: "Already famous."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Noddy330](http://thetimberyard.blogspot.com/2013/09/eminent-v-preeminent.html),

> Eminent v preeminent
>
> Q: What's the difference between **"eminent"** and **"preeminent**" in usage? W*ould a distinguished faculty member be described as an "eminent professor" or a "preeminent professor"?*
>
> A: **It's a matter of degree**. Eminent means that someone or something has become distinguished and stands out from the crowd. **There may several eminent people in a field**. **Preeminent means more like peerless, the most eminent of the eminent, the leading authority.**
>
> **em·i·nent**
>
> 1.high in station, rank, or repute; prominent; distinguished: eminent statesmen.
>
> 2.conspicuous, signal, or noteworthy: eminent fairness.
>
> 3.lofty; high: eminent peaks.
>
> 4.prominent; projecting; protruding: an eminent nose.
>
> From http://dictionary.reference.com
>
> **pre·em·i·nent**
>
> eminent above or before others; superior; surpassing: He is preeminent in his profession.
>
> From http://dictionary.reference.com

[WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/preeminent/eminent)says,

> Preeminent is a derived term of eminent.
>
> As adjectives the difference between preeminent and eminent is that preeminent is exceeding others in quality or rank; of outstanding excellence, extremely notable or important while eminent is (archaic) high, lofty; towering; prominent

Examples of preeminent in a sentence can be found at [Sentence Your Dictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/preeminent)

Comment: "The Timber Yard" is not an authentic source, though the information seems helpful. The blogger was quoting from Yahoo-Answers, the correct attribution.

Comment: I haven't so far found WikiDiff to be a reliable source, either. Whenever I've consulted it, it has read more like a bot that simply paraphrases the question.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at Merriam-Webster's definition of [**eminence**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eminence) (*eminent* "exhibits *eminence*"), we see:

> **1** : a position of prominence or superiority
>   **2** : one that is eminent, prominent, or lofty: such as
>   **a** : a person of high rank or attainments —often used as a title for a cardinal

And looking at its definition of [**paramount**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paramount) (*preeminence* has "*paramount* rank"):

> : superior to all others : supreme • a matter of *paramount* importance • Unemployment was the *paramount* issue in the election.

Therefore, while you can have multiple people who are are all **eminent** within a field, you can only have *one* who is **preeminent**.